# Line size by number of observations of a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot created from the `mtcars` data set and this code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, colour = factor(gear))) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

I want the line size of the linear regression lines to be proportional to the number of observations in each level of `factor(gear)`:

```
> count(factor(mtcars$gear))
  x freq
  3   15
  4   12
  5    5
```

I've tried calling `size =` `..count..` and `..n..`, inside the main `ggplot` call and the `geom_smooth` call with no luck.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

line_size <- count(factor(mtcars$gear))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, colour = factor(gear), size=factor(gear))) +
    geom_point(size=element_blank()) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
    scale_size_manual(values=line_size$freq/4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works on the `mtcars` data set, however on my actual data set (60k obs.) all I get is a light grey background (no lines, points, scales, etc.). Why could this be happening? EDIT: I divided by 10,000 based on your edit to reduce the line size, it works now!

Comment: Glad it worked! Good point, adding `line_size$freq <- line_size/max(line_size$freq)` before you plot would be a good idea. Then you can more easily scale the line size in the `scale_size_manual` line.